# How can I save my azure account so that I won't have to type my password again

Tags: command-line-interface, azure

I'm using the `azure cli` tools in a *nix machine to manage my personal vms in an Azure account. I was wondering if there is a way to save my login credentials such that I will not have to redo the `azure login` command neither type my password/credentials.

I downloaded my account settings using `azure account download` and imported on my machine using `azure account import`, however when I restart my session I still need to do the manual login step.

Thus, is there a way to setup azure cli to save my account details so that I won't have to manually login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `azure login` you are actually getting a token which only has a limited lifetime so even if you could persist across sessions it would expire after 12 hours anyway.  It is possible but **not advised** to specify the username and password as part of your script:

```
azure login -u $username -p $password
```

To do this you must be using an Azure Active Directory account to authenticate, assuming that you are willing to take this risk on given the fact you are managing your *personal* Azure Subscription this may be the easiest option.

In my experience, there are two approaches that would be more suitable in a company, enterprise or high-risk scenario:

### Azure Automation

[Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/automation/) is an Azure Platform service that allows you to build parameterized workflows within Azure that you can trigger on a schedule, from the web UI or from the command line.  Repetitive tasks are simplified because the environment the workflows run in is consistent across time and multiple environments.

### Azure Active Directory Service Principals

Authentication with Azure using [Service Principals](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#authenticate-with-certificate---azure-cli) allows you to use a certificate (`.pfx`) to login to Azure, assuming said certificate is stored without a password then you can achieve password-less login by following these steps:

1. Generate a public/private key pair to use for authentication.
2. Create a new Azure Active Directory Application
3. Create a new Service Principal for your AAD Application
4. Grant permission to your Subscription to your Service Principal
5. Authenticate with your Service Principal in your scripts

   ```
   cert=$(openssl x509 -in "./examplecert.pem" -fingerprint -noout | sed 's/SHA1 Fingerprint=//g'  | sed 's/://g'
   tenantId=$(azure account show -s <subscriptionId> --json | jq -r '.[0].tenantId')
   appId=$(azure ad app show --search exampleapp --json | jq -r '.[0].appId')
   azure login --service-principal --tenant "$tenantId" -u "$appId" --certificate-file ./examplecert.pem --thumbprint "$cert"
   ```

Comment: Thanks! It's just for my personal account. But I think its better to just do the manual azure login then...